# I get Errors in Eclipse right after I Export

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am a beginner, and am starting to make an android application in Eclipse.

I have no errors or anything at first. When I try to export it says no errors and lets me. But right after I export the project as an APK, there are about 100 errors.

I turned off Build Automatically because some people said it helped, but it is not working for me.

Any ideas?

Please Help

Errors I Get
 - cannot be resolved
 - cannot be resolved to a type
 - cannot be resolved to a variable
 - must implement the  abstract method
 - implements the method is undefined

None of these show up before, but just suddenly appear after I export.

Comment: let me know if you need more details

Comment: It would really help people helping you if you include the error messages.

Comment: looks like some third party libraries are missing from classpath. open type declaration for which there are errors and check if they are included in classpath. Also you can try delete `.metadata` from your workspace and import the entire project.

Comment: well the thing is that my friend made this app, and it worked perfectly for him. i'm editing it for him and i get all these errors.

Answer (score 0):

I gues your eclipse do not export the apk with some jar(s) that you use

right click to your project->properties->java buildpath->order import & export

check the jar that you think should be in apk file after export.
some jar(s) are missing